# Compare addresses pulled from an XML document in different formats

Tags: python, string-comparison

I'm trying to figure out how to compare two address fields I am pulling from two XML sources.  One returns the address in this format:

```
123 Main St
```

and the other:

```
123 MAIN ST
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
x = address1  <---first address format i states
y = address2   <---and the second

if x.upper() == y.upper():
   print "correct"
else:
   print "incorrect"
```

This does not seem to work, I'm assuming it is because I am trying to set the entire string of the address to uppercase but that wont work with a number.  My question is how would I compare two addresses that are returned in different formats, a strait if x = y comparison is not working to compare the addresses.

Comment: `'123 Main St'.upper() == '123 MAIN ST'.upper()` gives `True`; perhaps there is a whitespace problem instead? Try `x.strip().upper() == y.strip().upper()`.

Comment: Since numbers are unaffected by `.upper()` that's not your problem in any case.

Comment: you need to compare two values (strings in your case) with `==`, not `=`

Comment: ok wasnt sure if the numbers were affected or not (noob, sorry) ill try using strip now and let you know if it works for me although i didnt see any white spaces in the xml

Comment: @bmu sorry, that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert both addresses in lower case with .lower() and subsequently compare them.

Lower or Upper case are irrelevant, probably the issue is that you were using the operator "=" instead of "==" causing an assignment.

For example:

```
x = '123 Main St'
y = '123 MAIN ST'

new_x = x.lower()
new_y = y.lower()



if new_x == new_y :
   print "correct"
else:
   print "incorrect"
```